# fprintf() C erro ao imprimir, valor exibido(-1,#R) diferente do a ser alocado(0)

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um programa que basicamente pega uma float, calcula uma porcentagem sob o valor caso queira gravar, irá gravar as informações em um txt para poder ser incrementada agora(basicamente utilizado como banco de dados). O problema vem no seguinte aspecto. Ao deletar o arquivo txt e rodar o programa(que verifica se o arquivo existe, caso não cria ele), o problema surge que após a criação, existe um fprintf() que imprimi valores padrões a serem usado, porém não é impresso nada no arquivo até a 2 execução(a primeira da erro e fecha o programa, obviamente).
Código da dentro da main da abertura do arquivo e da criação dele.

```
arq = fopen("dados.txt","r+");
if (arq == NULL){
    arq = fopen("dados.txt","wb");
    printf("Arquivo \"dados.txt\" inexistente!\nCriando novo arquivo.\n\n");
    fprintf(arq, "Terreno %2.2f\n",Terreno);
    fprintf(arq, "CNH  %2.2f\n",CNH);
    fprintf(arq, "Contas %2.2f\n",Contas);
    fprintf(arq, "Poupança %2.2f\n",Poupanca);
    fprintf(arq, "Lazer %2.2f\n",Lazer);
    fprintf(arq, "Utilitários %2.2f\n",Utilitarios);
}
```

E agora o código de fscan() e fprintf final, o que exibe no programa.

```
printf("-==Exibição de valores armazenados==-\n");
    printf("+----------------------+\n");
    fscanf(arq, "%s %f", TextoAux, &AcmTerreno);
    AcmTerreno += Terreno;
    printf("|%s     = %8.2f|\n", TextoAux,AcmTerreno);

    fscanf(arq, "%s %f", TextoAux, &AcmCNH);
    AcmCNH += CNH;
    printf("|%s         = %8.2f|\n", TextoAux,AcmCNH);

    fscanf(arq, "%s %f", TextoAux, &AcmContas);
    AcmContas += CNH;
    printf("|%s      = %8.2f|\n", TextoAux,AcmContas);

    fscanf(arq, "%s %f", TextoAux, &AcmPoupanca);
    AcmPoupanca += Poupanca;
    printf("|%s    = %8.2f|\n", TextoAux,AcmPoupanca);

    fscanf(arq, "%s %f", TextoAux, &AcmLazer);
    AcmLazer += Lazer;
    printf("|%s       = %8.2f|\n", TextoAux,AcmLazer);

    fscanf(arq, "%s %f", TextoAux, &AcmUtilitarios);
    AcmUtilitarios += Utilitarios;
    printf("|%s = %8.2f|\n", TextoAux,AcmUtilitarios);
    printf("+----------------------+\n");   
    fprintf(arq, "Terreno %2.2f\n",AcmTerreno);
    fprintf(arq, "CNH  %2.2f\n",AcmCNH);
    fprintf(arq, "Contas %2.2f\n",AcmContas);
    fprintf(arq, "Poupança %2.2f\n",AcmPoupanca);
    fprintf(arq, "Lazer %2.2f\n",AcmLazer);
    fprintf(arq, "Utilitários %2.2f\n",AcmUtilitarios);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguem dois exemplos baseados na sua linha de racíocinio.

**1) Leitura/Gravação em modo texto:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct registro_s
{
    double terreno;
    double CNH;
    double contas;
    double poupanca;
    double lazer;
    double utilitarios;
} registro_t;


size_t gravar_registro( const char * arq, registro_t * rec )
{
    FILE * fp = fopen( arq, "w" );

    if(!fp)
        return -1;

    fprintf( fp, "%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf\n", rec->terreno, rec->CNH, rec->contas, rec->poupanca, rec->lazer, rec->utilitarios );

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}


size_t ler_registro( const char * arq, registro_t * rec )
{
    FILE * fp = fopen( arq, "r" );

    if(!fp)
        return -1;

    fscanf( fp, "%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf\n", &rec->terreno, &rec->CNH, &rec->contas, &rec->poupanca, &rec->lazer, &rec->utilitarios );

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}


void exibir_registro( registro_t * rec )
{
    printf("Terreno    : %2.2f\n", rec->terreno );
    printf("CNH        : %2.2f\n", rec->CNH );
    printf("Contas     : %2.2f\n", rec->contas );
    printf("Poupanca   : %2.2f\n", rec->poupanca );
    printf("Lazer      : %2.2f\n", rec->lazer );
    printf("Utilitários: %2.2f\n", rec->utilitarios );
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    registro_t a;
    registro_t b;

    /* Preenche registro A com os dados */
    a.terreno = 1.123;
    a.CNH = 2.468;
    a.contas = 9.999;
    a.poupanca = 0.1;
    a.lazer = 0.0;
    a.utilitarios = 100.10;

    /* Grava registro A no arquivo */
    gravar_registro( "teste.txt", &a );

    /* Le conteudo do arquivo e preenche registro B */
    ler_registro( "teste.txt", &b );

    /* Exibe registro B */
    exibir_registro( &b );

    return 0;
}
```

**2) Leitura/Gravação em modo binário:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct registro_s
{
    double terreno;
    double CNH;
    double contas;
    double poupanca;
    double lazer;
    double utilitarios;
} registro_t;


size_t gravar_registro( const char * arq, registro_t * rec )
{
    size_t nbytes = 0L;
    FILE * fp = fopen( arq, "wb" );

    if(!fp)
        return -1;

    nbytes = fwrite( rec, sizeof(registro_t), 1, fp );

    fclose(fp);

    return nbytes;
}


size_t ler_registro( const char * arq, registro_t * rec )
{
    size_t nbytes = 0L;
    FILE * fp = fopen( arq, "rb" );

    if(!fp)
        return -1;

    nbytes = fread( rec, sizeof(registro_t), 1, fp );

    fclose(fp);

    return nbytes;
}


void exibir_registro( registro_t * rec )
{
    printf("Terreno    : %2.2f\n", rec->terreno );
    printf("CNH        : %2.2f\n", rec->CNH );
    printf("Contas     : %2.2f\n", rec->contas );
    printf("Poupanca   : %2.2f\n", rec->poupanca );
    printf("Lazer      : %2.2f\n", rec->lazer );
    printf("Utilitários: %2.2f\n", rec->utilitarios );
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    registro_t a;
    registro_t b;

    /* Preenche registro A com os dados */
    a.terreno = 1.123;
    a.CNH = 2.468;
    a.contas = 9.999;
    a.poupanca = 0.1;
    a.lazer = 0.0;
    a.utilitarios = 100.10;

    /* Grava registro A no arquivo */
    gravar_registro( "teste.bin", &a );

    /* Le conteudo do arquivo e preenche registro B */
    ler_registro( "teste.bin", &b );

    /* Exibe registro B */
    exibir_registro( &b );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Vou ajustar o código para que faça o que eu quero e testar, a principio parece que vai melhorar(e muito) o que quero fazer.